# What is the dichotomy called when being implicitly 'without' when one says to look 'within', and what does it mean?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind-body, subjectivity, objectivity

I think the phrase 'Look within' is used often in the context of meditation. If someone can actually perform the act of looking within, it implicitly means that someone is currently 'without', and thus looking 'within' from 'without'.

Perhaps I totally misunderstand the whole concept of 'looking within'. If someone would ask me 'how do you look within'? I would describe it as focus on the bodily sensations and emotions, where you experience your inner world.

Some few meditations sessions ago I experienced something new (for me). I can best describe it as I looked 'without' from a 'within' experience. I already turned 'inwards', woke up, but not to my body, but more to stream if visual data that I could point my attention towards. It felt similar to a lucid dream, but I am certain I didn't phsyically fell asleep as I still sat up right.

So this got me thinking. Where am I, functionally speaking, when I can start to look within. And it implies one can also look 'without', starting from a 'within' experience.

I am looking for a description/concept/definition that describes this dichotomy, or this context. Preferably from a more holistic viewpoint, where the dichotomy of 'within'/'without' is transcended, so I can truly wrap my mind around it.

As a believer in a reality where objectivity not truly exists, and everything could be described in functions (or methods, like in programming or mathematics) I hope to read a 'functional' answer.
References to literature are also more than welcome!